# Basic gTTS library usage causes RuntimeError in Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.7, google-text-to-speech

I have successfully installed the [`gTTS`](https://pypi.org/project/gTTS/) (Google text-to-speech) library on my machine, and I ran this simple code:

```py
from gtts import gTTS
tts = gTTS('hello')
```

But I get this error:

```
 "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gtts/tts.py", line 114, in __init__
    for k, v in locals().items():
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to be doing anything wrong. It appears to be a simple bug in the `gTTS` library. [The offending code](https://github.com/pndurette/gTTS/blob/2c99b86a45a862913600a113c1b361b8aa9aca3f/gtts/tts.py#L113) is below: the code is only for debugging purposes.

```py
        # Debug
        for k, v in locals().items():
            if k == 'self':
                continue
            log.debug("%s: %s", k, v)
```

`locals()` returns a dictionary of local variables. It appears to be an [undocumented](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#locals) behaviour that this dictionary is a real-time view of the local variables, so it is updated dynamically when new local variables are declared, at least in some versions of Python (I'm using 3.6.2):

```py
>>> the_locals = locals()
>>> len(the_locals)
8
>>> 'x' in the_locals
False
>>> x = 12
>>> len(the_locals)
9
>>> 'x' in the_locals
True
```

So, the problem is caused by the assignment to `k` in the `__init__` method while iterating over this dictionary. The assignment creates a new local variable, adding it to the dictionary while it is being iterated over, which is a no-no and causes the error to be raised.

The solution would be to iterate over a copy of the dictionary, for example:

```py
for k, v in dict(locals()).items():
    ...
```

This seems to have been [reported to the library's issue tracker](https://github.com/pndurette/gTTS/issues/134) on GitHub in 2018, but the issue was closed without being fixed, presumably because the person who opened the issue did not provide enough information. I suggest [opening a new issue](https://github.com/pndurette/gTTS/issues) there yourself, and providing as much information as possible (a link to this Stack Overflow question would probably help).